# Starting with jPOS

Tags: jpos

I have downloaded jPOS-master.zip from this link. (https://github.com/jpos/jPOS ).

Ran the command `gradle clean dist installApp`

Found jPOS-master\jpos\build\install\jpos\jpos-1.9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar

Ran the command `java -jar jpos-1.9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Got the below console:

```
<log realm="Q2.system" at="Mon Dec 30 14:47:08 IST 2013.183" lifespan="10ms">
  <info>
    Q2 started, deployDir=D:\jPOS-master\jPOS-master\jpos\build\install\jpos\deploy

    jPOS 1.9.5-SNAPSHOT unknown/unknown (2013-12-30 14:44:39 IST)

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

jPOS Community Edition, licensed under GNU AGPL v3.0.
This software is probably not suitable for commercial use.
Please see http://jpos.org/license for details.

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (Darwin)

iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJMolHDAAoJEOQyeO71nYtFv74H/3OgehDGEy1VXp2U3/GcAobg
HH2eZjPUz53r38ARPiU3pzm9LwDa3WZgJJaa/b9VrJwKvbPwe9+0kY3gScDE1skT
ladHt+KHHmGQArEutkzHlpZa73RbroFEIa1qmN6MaDEHGoxZqDh0Sv2cpvOaVYGO
St8ZaddLBPC17bSjAPWo9sWbvL7FgPFOHhnPmbeux8SLtnfWxXWsgo5hLBanKmO1
1z+I/w/6DL6ZYZU6bAJUk+eyVVImJqw0x3IEElI07Nh9MC6BA4iJ77ejobj8HI2r
q9ulRPEqH9NR79619lNKVUkE206dVlXo7xHmJS1QZy5v/GT66xBxyDVfTduPFXk=
=oP+v
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="Mon Dec 30 14:47:08 IST 2013.200" lifespan="8ms">
  <info>
    deploy: D:\jPOS-master\jPOS-master\jpos\build\install\jpos\deploy\99_sysmon.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.qbean.SystemMonitor" at="Mon Dec 30 14:47:08 IST 2013.202">
  <info>
    Starting SystemMonitor
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.qbean.SystemMonitor" at="Mon Dec 30 14:47:08 IST 2013.203">
  <info>
               OS: Windows 7
             host: *****/*******
          version: 1.9.5-SNAPSHOT (unknown)
         instance: a0032410-aff4-4128-9bf1-1d14966f2ea9
           uptime: 00:00:00.280
       processors: 4
           drift : 0
    memory(t/u/f): 121/8/113
          threads: 4
            Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
            Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
            Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
            Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
            Thread[Q2-a0032410-aff4-4128-9bf1-1d14966f2ea9,5,main]
            Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
            Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
            Thread[SystemMonitor,5,main]
    name-registrar:
      logger.Q2.buffered: org.jpos.util.BufferedLogListener
      logger.Q2: org.jpos.util.Logger
  </info>
</log>
```

When I do a telnet to localhost i get below exception .. which means that Q2 Server is not up.

```
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 10000: Connect failed
```

When I do a gradle test I get the below exception

```
org.jpos.iso.packagers.PackagerTestCase > testXMLPackager FAILED
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError at PackagerTestCase.java:214

org.jpos.util.DailyLogListenerTest > testLogRotationAndCompressionWorks FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at DailyLogListenerTest.java:303
> Building > :jpos:test > 3145 tests completed, 2 failed, 54 skipped
```

Can somebody please help as how to bring up the Q2 Server ? I have read proguide-draft.pdf, but could not understand what is the issue. I want to get a server up and running and hit it with some sample requests and get the responses back.

Do I need put some more xmls in deploy directory for Server deployment ? Also after running gradle installApp I could not find any q2.bat in the install directory, I Could find only  ..

```
 bsh q2 start stop files.
```

Thanks in advance,
Varun Kumar A.

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody please help as how to bring up the Q2 Server ? I have
>   read proguide-draft.pdf, but could not understand what is the issue. I
>   want to get a server up and running and hit it with some sample
>   requests and get the responses back.

You can use **"jpos-template"** for server and client simulation. Detail how to is here in these beautiful blog posts. As per the ducumentation,
[Implementing a jpos dateway] page no 8

> We connect here to jPOS' auto-responder, which is usually up and
>   listening on port 9000. You could use a local server, for example
>   based on jPOS-EE's server simulator.

You can use **server simulator** as a auto responder (remote host as per diagram) to prepare a demo environment of jpos.

[Sever Simulator](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/tutorial.adoc)

[Client Simulator](http://jpos.org/blog/2013/07/setting-up-the-client-simulator/)

Answer (score 0):

Your serve is not deployed properly, you need to add `serversimulator.bsh` and `serversimulator.xml` to corresponding folders and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add jposee-server-simulator dependency to your project? after add the dependency, you need to execute bellow gradle command:

> installResources

to retrieve the *serversimulator.bsh* and *05_serversimulator.xml* from jposee-server-simulator module.

This tutorials describe how to use jpos-template to setup jpos-ee project and run / debug the project on eclipse IDE.
https://nacadev.com/introduction-to-jpos-ee/